Ubuntu VM Ext4-fs remounting in read-only on citrix
I have this issue of a couple of our minio servers based on ubuntu server are going into read only on the data drive only, this disrupts the service and slows it down while it timeouts with each request since the service is still up but read only. I tried looking into this but i found no issues with our environment and the minio servers are the only machines affected by this. All the storage is on a NAS attached to our citrix environment. Any leads at all would be greatly appreciated
[1337951.013926] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 436375784 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x3000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[1337951.013942] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 8467112 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x3000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[1337951.013967] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 3504792 op 0x1: (WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[1337951.014024] EXT4-fs error (device xvdb1): __ext4_find_entry:1682: inode #1650776: comm minio: reading directory lblock 0
[1337956.863899] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 427890432 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x3000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[1337956.864107] EXT4-fs error (device xvdb1): __ext4_find_entry:1682: inode #13370238: comm minio: reading directory lblock 0
[1337968.932317] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvda, sector 5776784 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x84700 phys_seg 11 prio class 0
[1337968.932424] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvda, sector 5776872 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x84700 phys_seg 11 prio class 0
[1337968.932484] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvda, sector 5776960 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x84700 phys_seg 11 prio class 0
[1337973.963602] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvda, sector 5478792 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 10 prio class 0
[1337973.963744] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvda, sector 5478808 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[1337973.963799] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvda, sector 5478872 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[1337973.963833] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvda, sector 5478920 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[1337973.964366] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvda, sector 5478968 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[1337992.085614] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 302691336 op 0x1: (WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 5 prio class 0
[1337992.086104] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvda, sector 12710542 op 0x1: (WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[1337992.086544] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 1129234
[1337992.086949] Buffer I/O error on device xvdb1, logical block 437843
[1337992.087375] Aborting journal on device xvdb1-8
[1338010.145335] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvda, sector 5776912 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[1338010.145739] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvda, sector 12441248 op 0x1: (WRITE) flags 0xB00 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[1338010.146195] Aborting journal on device dm-0-8
[1338015.177898] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvda, sector 5478920 op 0x0: (READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[1338018.296465] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_journal_check_start:83: comm systemd-journal: Detected aborted journal
[1338018.326114] EXT4-fs (dm-0): Remounting filesystem read-only
[1338023.608064] EXT4-fs error (device xvdb1): ext4_journal_check_start:83: comm minio: Detected aborted journal
[1338023.637702] EXT4-fs (xvdb1): Remounting filesystem read-only

I am able to remount the file system after scanning for errors, then it works fine for a while and the issues occurs again.
vDistributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:
Codename:
22.04
jammy
:~$ uname -r
5.15.0-113-generic

